# jTable row count VS model row count

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a `jTable` which loads data from a DB query
This load produces 32 results, thus 32 rows in the `TableModel` 
With `myTable.getRowCount()` i correctly get 32

Then i create a new empty model and load it into the table
After that, if i call `myTable.getRowCount()` i still get 32
But if i call myModel.getRowCount() i correctly get 0!

Why there should be difference between table.getRowCount() and model.getRowCount() if my table is using the model?

```
...
System.out.println(myTable.getRowCount());  // 32


String[] columnNames= {null};
DefaultTableModel emptyModel= new DefaultTableModel(null, columnNames);
emptyModel.setRowCount(0);
myTable.setModel(emptyModel);

System.out.println(myTable.getRowCount());  // still 32, expecting 0
System.out.println(emptyModel.getRowCount());  // 0 as expected
```

Comment: Did you by any chance add a custom row sorter to your table?

Comment: I am using a javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter, like this:  myTable.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(model));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a custom RowSorter (or any RowSorter for that matter), one must take care to make sure the models of the sorter and the table always match. As specified in the `setRowSorter` Javadoc:

> If the underlying model of the RowSorter differs from that of this JTable undefined behavior will result.

The `setModel` method of the JTable will not update the row sorter, unless you are using a default automatic one (by setting the `autoCreateRowSorter` flag).

As such, you should

- keep a reference to your sorter and update its model as well
  **OR**
- use the default row sorter by setting `setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)` on your table and not a custom one,

Comment: It may be a stupid question, but why should a rowsorter change the row count? If i have 10 rows and i sort them in every possible way, they should always remain 10 rows right?

Comment: Row sorters not only do sorting, they also do row filtering

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a verifiable code of yours? because i tried with the following code and the model changed without any issues.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
                new Object[][] { { "some", "text" }, { "any", "text" },
                        { "even", "more" }, { "text", "strings" },
                        { "and", "other" }, { "text", "values" } },
                new Object[] { "Column 1", "Column 2" });
        String[] columnNames= {null};
        DefaultTableModel model1 = new DefaultTableModel(null,columnNames);
        model1.setRowCount(0);


        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        table.setModel(model1);
    }
```

Comment: my model changes correctly, the jtable gets empty after the new model load! the only thing that doesn't change is the value returned from myTable.getRowCount(), which still counts 32

Comment: +1, @Maik, it has been 45 minutes since you posted the above comment, yet you still haven't posted your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. The `SSCCE` posted here DOES work so we can't tell what you are doing differently based on the few random lines of code you posted.

Comment: @camickr you`re right. The problem is that i cannot provide a SSCCE that works like my application! I've tried the code of Hirak and it works correctly. But if i paste the same, identycal code into my application, table.getRowCount() returns the wrong number!?! The olny difference is that my tabel is a variable class, but it doesn't change things (already tried in an example). I really don't know where to stomp my head...

Comment: I have edited the question: table.getRowCount() works wrong, but model.getRowCount() works right!