# Problems with default table model

Tags: java, jtable, tablemodel

I am creating java editable table, and faced to problem: it "crashes" after reading data. Here is my table:

```
table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]
{"#","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"},8);
table.setModel(tableModel);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(22);
```

Reading from txt:

```
OK4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    File f = new File(fileName);
    if(f.exists()){
        try {
            tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"#","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"},0);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line = br.readLine();
            String[] colHeaders = line.split("\\s+");
            tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(colHeaders);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = line.split("\\s+");
                tableModel.addRow(data);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "this day is not saved");
    };
    table.setModel(tableModel);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(22);
});
```

And main problems causing my sum field:

```
OK3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int sum=0;
        int number;
        Object smth;
        String Smth;
        int kint2 = table.getRowCount()-1;
        if(table.getValueAt(kint2, 1)=="total:"){

        }else{
            tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{});
            int a = table.getRowCount()-1;
            table.setValueAt("total:", a, 1);
        }
        for (int j = 2; j < 8; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount()-1; i++) {
                smth = table.getValueAt(i,j);
                Smth = (String) smth;
                if (smth==null){
                    number=0;
                }else{
                    number=Integer.parseInt(Smth);
                }
                sum=sum+number;
            }
            table.setValueAt(sum, table.getRowCount()-1, j);
            sum=0;
        }
    }
});
```

Application stops calculate sum after being read from txt or calculates only first 4 rows sum. Have it something to do with my `tableModel`?

Thank you for answers.

Comment: What is the error message displayed in console. I think the problem is at parseInt. You used split and readLine() but you cannot be sure that there are not special characters in "Smth". try removing "\n" first and trim().

Comment: No error mesages. Just OK3 override event crashes. I mean it stops calculate sum if OK2 was used.

Comment: Do you use them at the same time? I am thinking about a bug at tablemodel.getRowCount()

Comment: Nope, Just tested. I have 2 other actions delete and add rows. After being readed from text file > deleted all rows > and added all new rows.  So whole table data has been cleaned, and it still do not calculates sum, only 3 of first rows.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626951/jtable-row-count-vs-model-row-count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you add new rows with tablemodel and count rows with table. As discussed at "[jTable row count VS model row count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626951/jtable-row-count-vs-model-row-count)" your table won't update the rows count so always use  tablemodel.getRowCount()

Comment: Youp, that seems been a problem. Thank you!