# Saving JTable contents as a text file

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jtable

I am making a restaurant ordering system menu for homework in Java. I am to make a receipt in the form of the program creating a text file with the table contents in it. I am however having trouble doing this. All my table contents are strings.

This is the code for exporting the contents of the table:

```
try{       
   BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Data.txt"));
   for(int i = 0 ; i < tableSalesFood.getColumnCount() ; i++){
       bfw.write(tableSalesFood.getColumnName(i));
       bfw.write("\t");
   }

   for (int i = 0 ; i < tableSalesFood.getRowCount(); i++){
       bfw.newLine();
       for(int j = 0 ; j < tableSalesFood.getColumnCount();j++){
          bfw.write((String)(tableSalesFood.getValueAt(i,j)));
          bfw.write("\t");;
       }
   }

   bfw.close();   
   }catch(Exception ex){
      ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```

The program returns the exception error when I click the button:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Comment: `tableSalesFood.getValueAt(i,j).toString()` getValueAt returns an Object, not a String. The Object may be a String, an Integer, a Double, or a RubberDucky. Do not cast to String, invoke the toString method.

Comment: For serialization / deserialization to/from text, It is better to use the underlying `TableModel` to/from text, rather than the JTable itself.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it's caused by `(String)(tableSalesFood.getValueAt(i,j)`, you're trying to cast Integer to a String. Please make sure you know what a `ClassCastException` is, see for instance this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907360/can-someone-explain-classcastexception-in-java).

You can fix the error by conversion, not casting:

```
Objects.toString(tableSalesFood.getValueAt(i,j), "");
```

Class `Objects` is defined in `java.util` package.

Comment: I did this, but it still gives me an error : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: are you using `Objects.toString`? Which line NullPointerException refers to?

Comment: yes, this is what I used: Objects.toString(tableSalesFood.getValueAt(i,j), "");

Comment: which line does NullPointerException refers to? that one with Objects.toString? or another line?

Comment: it already works. sorry and thank you. however, the only data in the txt file are the column names.

Comment: do you get blank lines, or just column names and that's all?

Comment: just column names.

Comment: so, your row count is 0, otherwise you would have writen blank lines to the file (or your text editor doesn't show whitespaces). I also think that something changed from yesterday, because if rowCount were 0 yesterday there wouldn't be any classcast exception. so first, please make sure that the rowCount is indeed 0 (just print it to console), and if it is -- you've got to deal with some other error

Comment: yep. rowCount s 0.

Comment: so, that's completely different story. I would suggest to ask a new question on why it's zero. because there might be a number of reasons why it is (first that comes to mind is row filtering, see this for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626951/jtable-row-count-vs-model-row-count). after this problem is solved, the code that writes values to the file should work just fine

Answer (score 1):

You can actually create tab-separated values by using JTable’s default TransferHandler to export the JTable’s headers and values as a String:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
table.getTransferHandler().exportToClipboard(table, clipboard,
    TransferHandler.COPY);

try {
    String text = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    Files.write(Paths.get("Data.txt"), Collections.singleton(text),
        Charset.defaultCharset());
} catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it the Data.txt file doesn't contain the contents of the table. It contains this:Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
table.getTransferHandler().exportToClipboard(table, clipboard,
    TransferHandler.COPY);

try {
    String text = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    Files.write(Paths.get("Data.txt"), Collections.singleton(text),
        Charset.defaultCharset());
} catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}